# Can't hear others (Skype and Discord) and other programs but they can hear me

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, skype, microphone

I recently switched to Linux and I'm having an issue with audio when calling people on Skype and Discord. My audio works for both recording and playing sounds but if i'm calling my friends on Skype or Discord they can hear me but I can't hear any sounds. I tried force restarting pulseaudio and keeping the settings to 'Default Device' on Skype/Discord but they don't work.

Comment: I've had this issue with Discord and it turned out to be the program itself that had the wrong output device selected. Have you tried setting it manually to the device you want to use in the program, rather than the default?

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced this problem but I was not using Ubuntu instead I was using Windows only.

I guess there's a third-party app messing up with voice settings or maybe there might have been an issue while installing.

I would highly recommend you test it with the Discord Web Version and if you still **[can't hear people on discord](https://techcrucial.com/cant-hear-people-on-discord/)** then here's are some more methods which you can follow. Hope it would be helpful.

Cheers,
Sandra Smith

Answer (score 1):

I wasnt able to hear anything in discord, but others were able to hear me. I have fixed this by:

1. Open discord/skype, joined a voice chat
2. went to Sound settings
3. Applications tab Made webRTC sound level louder

[how_to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inEwj.png)
[image]

Comment: My OS Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, discord Stable 57334 (b1437cc)